# I want to fetch data from a collection firestore data base and store it into another collection of firestore data base

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
    runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
   title: 'Attendance App',
   theme: ThemeData(
     primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
       ),
   home: UserDashBoard(),
      );
  }
 }

  class UserDashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
          _UserDashBoardState createState() => _UserDashBoardState();
}     

     class _UserDashBoardState extends State<UserDashBoard> {
       bool hasMarkedAttendance = false;

         @override
         Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
           title: Text('User Panel'),
           ),
               body: Center(
              child: Column(
               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: hasMarkedAttendance ? null : markAttendance,
          child: Text('Mark Attendance'),
        ),
      ],
       ),
     ),
         );
        }

        void markAttendance() async {


        String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
        String studentname = '';
          String fatherName = '';
          DateTime currentDate = DateTime.now();
       
         // Retrieve user details from the "users" collection
         DocumentSnapshot userSnap = await                        

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(uid).get();
         if (userSnap.exists) {
     studentname = userSnap.get('studentname') ?? '';
  fatherName = userSnap.get('fathername') ?? '';
    }

// Check if attendance record already exists for the current user and current date
      DateTime startOfCurrentDate = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month, currentDate.day);
DateTime endOfCurrentDate = startOfCurrentDate.add(Duration(days: 1));

QuerySnapshot attendanceSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('attendance')
    .where('uid', isEqualTo: uid)
    .where('date', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startOfCurrentDate)
    .where('date', isLessThan: endOfCurrentDate)
    .get();

if (attendanceSnapshot.docs.isNotEmpty) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: Text('You have already marked your attendance for today.'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
} else {
  try {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('attendance').add({
      'uid': uid,
      'studentname': studentname,
      'fatherName': fatherName,
      'date': currentDate,
    });

    setState(() {
      hasMarkedAttendance = true;
    });

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Success'),
          content: Text('Your attendance has been marked.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Error'),``your text``
          content: Text('Failed to mark your attendance. Please try again.'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              child: Text('OK'),`your text`
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
     }
   }
 }


    }
```

I want to fetch data(studentname,fathernmae and uid) from the user collection and add it into new collection "attendance" with the current date so that one user only mark his attendance once in a day,
when evere mark attendance button is pressed ,  i want to fetch data from the user collection and add it into attendance colelction, but it onle stored current data , and uid, studentname and fathername fields remains empry

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what's wrong with the code you have now, or explain in more detail what specifically you're stuck with. All you have right now is a somewhat complex task to perform, but you haven't said anything at all about the code. I suggest running through this [checklist](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/checklist) to make sure you've done everything you can to write a good question.

Comment: I want to fetch some details form user collection and it to the new collection(attendance) on pressing the mark attendance button, but when i press the mark attendance biutton, only current date was adding in the attendance colelction and the uid,studentname,fatehr name wase remainign empty @DougStevenson